# How do you add Indian rupee symbol using Python?

Tags: python

I am looking to find an easy and intuitive way of printing an indian rupee symbol (₹) using Python 3.

```
print(u'\u20B9')
```

This code above didn't seem to work as I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a way to make this work without the need of external python libraries? If not then which python library is best suitable?

Comment: Isn't it printing it when you do `print('₹')`?

Comment: Check your system/editor encoding works fine for me.

Comment: @Nurqm  Yes, still same. Like other encodings work fine for example `print(u"\u00E8")` for è. But for some strange reason when it comes to '₹' it doesn't work.

Comment: @venky__ : I tried in it on an ipynb file and it works fine but not on a py file. Have you tried it on a py file?

Comment: Where are you running Python? Windows? Linux? Mac? Are you running from a terminal or some sort of IDE?

Comment: Works for me on windows 10 using cmd/IDLE/jupyter

Comment: @larsks  Windows, Komodo IDE. I am using python 3.

Comment: Did you try `print('\u20B9')` ?

Comment: It works in VScode when I run, but not in Komodo IDE. Idk why either.

Comment: @fountainhead Yeah.